# Please suggest what went wrong in my code

Tags: linguistics

My code are follow:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
%\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{mdwlist}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree,tikz-dependency}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{linguex}

\usepackage{showframe}
\def\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.125pt}

\begin{document}


We examine this issue through the lens of a language family that has received considerable attention in research on syntactic ergativity: the Mayan family. Mayan languages have been a particularly compelling testing ground for theories of syntactic egrativity because, while all of them exhibit ergative-absolutive marking, only some exhibit syntactic ergativity. For example, Q'anjob'al does not allow the ergative subject to be directly extracted \ref{initialqan}, while Ch'ol does \ref{initialchol} (see Coon, Mateo Pedro, and Preminger (CMP) 2014). %\nocite{CoonMateoPreminger:2014}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%test%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll Wenn jemand in die W\"uste zieht ... \\
If  someone in the desert draws and lives ... \\
\trans `if one retreats to the desert and ... '
\end{exe}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%test%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

I got error, please can any one suggest what went wrong in my tag?....

Comment: I think the problem is with `\begin{exe}` but I do not know why.

Comment: The error is caused by the `linguex` package, this has a different format for glosses than `gb4e`. So either remove `linguex` or use the syntax of that package (see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/linguex/doc/linguex-doc.pdf) instead of the `gb4e` syntax that you use now.